# Can't remove appEngineRoutingOverride on Google Cloud Tasks Queue

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I can't get my Cloud Tasks queue to stop overriding the app engine service routing. I created the queue through the GCP dashboard, not using queue.yml or anything else.

Description of the queue:

```
$ gcloud tasks queues describe import
appEngineRoutingOverride:
  host: my-project-id.uc.r.appspot.com
name: projects/my-project-id/locations/us-central1/queues/import
purgeTime: '2021-03-31T00:45:22.941195Z'
rateLimits:
  maxBurstSize: 100
  maxConcurrentDispatches: 1000
  maxDispatchesPerSecond: 500.0
retryConfig:
  maxAttempts: 100
  maxBackoff: 3600s
  maxDoublings: 16
  minBackoff: 0.100s
state: PAUSED
```

Attempting to clear the routing override flag with `--clear-routing-override` appears to be successful but does not actually clear the flag

```
$ gcloud tasks queues update import --clear-routing-override
WARNING: You are managing queues with gcloud, do not use queue.yaml or queue.xml in the future. More details at: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/queue-yaml.
Updated queue [import].
$ gcloud tasks queues describe import
appEngineRoutingOverride:
  host: my-project-id.uc.r.appspot.com
name: projects/my-project-id/locations/us-central1/queues/import
purgeTime: '2021-03-31T01:15:16.727288Z'
rateLimits:
  maxBurstSize: 20
  maxConcurrentDispatches: 1000
  maxDispatchesPerSecond: 100.0
retryConfig:
  maxAttempts: 100
  maxBackoff: 3600s
  maxDoublings: 16
  minBackoff: 0.100s
state: PAUSED
```

If I change the routing to another service with `--routing-override` the change is successful, but that means I can only have tasks pointing to one specific service in this queue. Additionally, if I change the routing, then click on `Edit Queue` on the Queue details panel the app engine routing override fields will be blank, not populated with the service I specified earlier. If I click save the `appEngineRoutingOverride` flag will reset to the `default` service host. Even if I change the override options through the `Edit Queue` panel, refresh, then open it back up the service will still not be populated, meaning if I change the service override once and somebody on my team needs to change another setting such as rate limits then the routing will be reset and things will break.

[imgur vid](https://i.imgur.com/rMlhPOZ.mp4) to clearly demonstrate the issue

EDIT: This has been reported on the GCP issue tracker a few times

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179701687
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177651361
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176221773

Comment: Oh I wish I found your post earlier. Just spent the last 4 hours fighting this. For some reason one of my queues somehow had it set. This must be a new feature they silently pushed and in true google cloud way I can barely find any docs on this and only find out about this feature after discovering it as a potential bug. Oh google cloud....

Comment: This question is life saving. I also just lost 4 hours before founding this treasure. I will open a support ticket directly to Google Cloud so that I least they put that as "Known Issues" in their documentation.

Answer (score 8):

Did some digging, DO NOT use the UI on could.google.com to create or update queues.

New ones will always have a `host` pointing to defaults.
And updated ones will get a `host` pointing to default.. and then you have silently messed up your queue.

Use the cli command to create and update queues

```
gcloud tasks queues update mey-new-queue --max-dispatches-per-second=10 --max-concurrent-dispatches=3
```

adjust the flags to what you need. This command works as an upsert

(just realized how I messed up my queue, I accidentally updated it through the web UI)

Comment: Just for the reference, if you want to clear the routing override with `gcloud`, you can run this:
`gcloud tasks queues update <queueName> --clear-routing-override`